# How can I handle collision issue in Triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a TRIGGER *(before update)* on a table like this:

```
UPDATE contact_us SET updated_at = unix_timestamp() WHERE id = new.id
```

And when I update a row of that table by using phpMyadmin, it throws this error:

[image]

To see it more clear:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'contact_us' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Maybe show the trigger as well?

Comment: @FMashiro [Ther you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW9Bv.png)

Comment: show store procedure?

Comment: @Ravi I don't have any!

Comment: I think you're creating an infinite loop, because your trigger is the same as the SQL statement you're trying to run. So, the trigger runs, and because it runs, it also calls itself, etc...

Comment: When this trigger called... when u manually update table

Comment: from where new.id comes?

Comment: @Ravi It's how trigger works.

Comment: @FMashiro Seems you're right. Do you have any solution?!

Comment: Get rid of the trigger. I don't see it's purpose if you're doing this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you do not need a trigger at all for this functionality, just use a timestamp or datetime field with [automatic initialisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html). So, define `updated_at` as follows:

   ```
   updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ```
2. If you insist on using a trigger for whatever reason, even then do not use a separate `update` statement to update the same table the trigger is defined on because that's a no go (endless loop). Use the `NEW` keyword to access the fields of the newly created record to modify a field's content:

   ```
   set NEW.updated_at = unix_timestamp();
   ```

Comment: Your first approach will work when a row is **created**, not **updated**.

Comment: @stack then add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the field definition as per the documentation suggests. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Sounds right, but how can I add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `updated_at` row now? I mean currently the table is created. Do I need `alter` ?

Comment: @stack well, you can try via saying abracadabra, but probably an alter table will do just fine. Use your favourite MySQL manager GUI to edit the field definition.

Comment: Ok, I found a option in the phpMyadmin which does that for me. But the datatype of that column is `int(11)` and I need to store `unix_timestamp()` *(which is a sequence of seconds)* in it, not `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Do you have any idea? Upvote btw

Comment: This is what the timestamp datatype is for in MySQL. Why do you try to reinvent the wheel?